# Github actions replacing firebase json in flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm running a Github action that automatically builds and releases a flutter project. But we use a dev and a production Firebase environment. so before the build I'd like to switch out the google-services.json from the dev to the production version. But I can't seem to find an easy way to do this. Or is there a better way to work with dev and production versions of Firebase inside flutter?

probably not very useful but here's the action in it's current state

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ stable ]

name: Build and Release 
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
      with:
        fetch-depth: '0'
    - name: Bump version and push tag
      id: tag
      uses: anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.17.2
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
        WITH_V: true
        RELEASE_BRANCHES: stable
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
        flutter-version: '1.17.3'
    - run: flutter pub get
    - run: flutter build appbundle
    - name: Create a Release APK
      uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
      with:
        artifacts: "build/app/outputs/bundle/release/*.aab"
        tag: ${{ steps.tag.outputs.tag }}
        token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

I'm very, very new to github actions and CI in general. any constructive feedback is always welcome!

Answer (score 7):

Not sure that's the most optimised solution but it's what I found being the easiest to update and maintain.

Step 1 : Store the google-services.json files in the secrets of your Github repository (that way you won't have to commit this file in your repo, that's a bonus) with names like FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEV and FIREBASE_CONFIG_PROD.

Step 2 : Create two workflows : one for the dev, triggered every pull-request for example, and the other one for the release, triggered by a commit on a specific branch like your did

Step 3 : Provide the google-service.json to your project

```
  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - name: Provide Firebase Android
    env:
      FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEV: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEV }}
    run: echo $FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEV > ./android/app/google-services.json
```

*Your Dev workflow should look like this*

Just edit this snippet to add the creation of the google-services.json to your iOS project and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was looking for this while setting up automated releases via github.